# Battery problem

Tags: 12.04, battery, desktop-environments

Ubuntu's unity eats up my Asus Eee PC's battery, in a few minutes, with Libreoffice running.

Should i reduce the memory usage of Libreoffice, or get a spare desktop environment?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider installing jupiter.

You can select several power modes with it, and it's very easy to control. It really saves out battery.

Open terminal and do this:

add the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
```

update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install jupiter

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

and to other people reading this and are using an Asus EEPC netbook, install this asswell

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee
```

Have a nice day :)

Comment: No problem, it is the first thing I install after a fresh ubuntu install :P